# Urllib2, tratamento de exceções

Tags: python, exceção, python-2.7

Sou um iniciante na arte da programação. Estou aprendendo a programar em Python através de um livro,

> Aprenda a Programar: A arte de ensinar o computador (Cesar Brod - Novatec Editora)

Em um dos exercícios, devo utilizar a biblioteca de funções Urllib2 para buscar uma determinada página web e verificar se existe uma determinada palavra ou expressão dentro dessa página (a ideia é utilizar esse processo num conjugador de verbos, verificando num dicionário online se o verbo digitado pelo usuário é regular).

Basicamente, isso é o que deveria acontecer:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> verbo = 'amar'
>>> pagina = urllib2.urlopen('http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + verbo)
>>> pagina = pagina.read()
>>> "Verbo regular" in pagina
True
>>>
```

Até aí, tudo bem. Porém, caso não exista uma página correspondente à palavra digitada pelo usuário, o seguinte erro aparece:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> verbo = '123ar'
>>> pagina = urllib2.urlopen('http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + verbo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>>> pagina = pagina.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pagina' is not defined
>>>
```

Bem, como a página em questão (http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/123ar) possui um código-fonte, eu imaginei que o programa o leria e faria a verificação da mesma forma, entretanto isso não acontece. Alguém poderia me sugerir uma solução?

P.S.: Caso eu não tenha sido muito claro, ou tenha deixado alguma informação importante de fora, por favor, me avisem. Outra coisa, eu costumo utilizar um Linux para programar, mas estou usando um Windows no momento, no entanto, o erro ocorre nos dois sistemas.

P.S.2: Perdoem-me por qualquer erro conceitual, como disse anteriormente, ainda sou um inciante na arte da programação. Falando nisso, estou aberto a dicas também =)

Comment: @ErlonCharles Valeu aí pela edição! =)

Comment: Por nda, tudo para melhorar a cominidade
:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve tratar este erro num bloco `try...except`, quando a função [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) não consegue abrir uma página, uma exceção [`HTTPError`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#httperror) é lançada (é uma subclasse de [`URLError`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#urlerror)), portanto para tratá-la faça o seguinte:

```
import urllib2

try:
    verbo = '123ar'
    pagina = urllib2.urlopen('http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/{0}'.format(verbo)).read()
    print ("Verbo regular" in pagina)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print ("Nao foi possivel abrir a pagina. Erro {0}".format(e.code))
```

> Bem, como a página em questão (http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/123ar)
>   possui um código-fonte, eu imaginei que o programa o leria e faria a
>   verificação da mesma forma, entretanto isso não acontece. Alguém
>   poderia me sugerir uma solução?

Isso acontece porque a [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) trabalha de modo diferente que [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#httperrorprocessor-objects) cita o seguinte:

> Para os códigos de erros diferentes de 200, o trabalho passa para o método manipulador `protocol_error_code`, via `OpenerDirector.error()`. Eventualmente, `urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler` irá gerar um `HTTPError` se nenhum outro manipulador lida com o erro.

Para contornar isto, existe duas maneiras, a primeira é pegar o código fonte no bloco `except`:

```
try:
    verbo = '123ar'
    pagina = urllib2.urlopen('http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/{0}'.format(verbo)).read()
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    pagina = e.fp.read()
```

E a segunda é usar a [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html):

```
import urllib

verbo = '123ar'
pagina = urllib.urlopen('http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/{0}'.format(verbo)).read()
print ("Verbo regular" in pagina)
```

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema. Muito obrigado, @qmechanik

Comment: @PedroA. Disponha. Atualizei a resposta, eu não tinha visto a segunda parte da sua pergunta.

Comment: Ah, tudo bem. A outra resposta já me ajudou muito, mas a nova facilitou ainda mais o meu trabalho, além de me ensinar ainda mais coisas. Novamente, obrigado.